# Uniquate = Eliminate or replace duplicates, make unique?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I am not a native English speaker and I need a word means **modifying a list/set to make it a unique-values list/set eliminating or replacing non-unique values with unique ones**. For instance;

```
"Dup", "Dup", "Dup" --> "Dup", "Dup1", "Dup2"
```

I am also aware of *[deduplication](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/48102/17418)* suggestion, but I can't settle for it. Because, it sounds me that it means **eliminating** (deleting) duplicate values, but not **replacing**.

So, the word **uniquate** meets this meaning or it is completely different thing? And any other suggestion?

**Edit:** I need a word reflects especially ***replacement***, but it is OK if it **also** reflects *eliminating*. I don't search for an answer focusing to only eliminating.

Comment: Your question title actually mentions _Eliminate ... duplicates_, so it's not surprising people addressed that IMO. You're actually trying to _replace duplicates with new items to guarantee uniqueness_ or similar.

Comment: Yes, I actually need a word for replacement. But not necessarily fit to only replacement, it can cover also eliminating beside the replacement.

Comment: If you can't explain what the operation _is_, I'm not sure how much luck you'll have naming it.

Comment: OK, edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea 'uniquate' is possible but few would understand its intention without a lot of context.

> **uniquify**

is not an officially recognized term, but uses the very productive and understandable suffix '-ify' meaning 'to make'. However this particular construction sounds too informal as a neologisms to be appropriate.

A single term is not necessary. You can say what is happening:

> **remove duplicates**

Comment: Thanks, _uniquify_ sounds better than _uniquate_. But "remove duplicates" doesn't reflect the actual operation in my case. As I said, I mean to "change duplicate instances of repeating items into another form, so they all are different from each other." For example: "Dup",Dup","Dup" => "Dup","Dup1","Dup2"

Comment: I've used _uniquify_ with no confusion in the past (and I think it's the right answer here). However, I'd suggest _deduplicate_ as a similarly well-understood replacement for _remove duplicates_.

Comment: I'm not unwilling to accept *uniquify* as a CS or mathematics coinage, but I can't find it in a dictionary anywhere. I'm also reluctant to trot out Google NGram searches as evidence, but *uniquify* flatlines there at 0.00%.

Comment: May increase after this :)

Comment: @Robusto - I'm not sure I've seen _uniquify_ around much either, but it seems to be an easily-understood coinage in IME.

Comment: @mmdemirbas: Not likely. NGrams only include printed matter, not web pages.

Comment: @mmdemirbas: your comment makes clear that 'remove' duplicates is -not- what you are after, that you want to preserve the same number of items in your list but those that are equal you want to distinguish somehow with an additional unique marker for each. So I'm guessing you want a shorter term for "an additional identifier to distinguish repeated items in a list"?

Comment: My point about 'uniquify' is that though it sounds OK it is a neologism and so is not preferred in technical writing (it is too informal sounding) unless it is not strange sounding. That is, the word doesn't 'exist' but people would easily understand it, but you probably don't want to use it.

Comment: I almost think I prefer *unique* as a verb over those other coinings for uniquification. Shop-jargon uses *deduping* pretty commonly.

Comment: I use **uniquify** in a programming context to mean "remove duplicates". I would use **disambiguate** (as per [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/181211/276872)) to mean "change duplicates to unique values".

Answer (score 2):

*Uniquate* and *uniquify* have no established currency in any context, but [here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22deduplicate%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are hundreds of written instances of [deduplicate](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=deduplicate&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=ftFzT_nxO-Gk0QXG4MgI&ved=0CCwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f66d7c49905cd037&biw=1316&bih=902), nearly all specifically about removing duplicate keys from lists.

It may be that doesn't suit OP if he wants to keep *all* records, simply altering [a keyfield in] one of each duplicated pair so they are in fact different. When I did that I called it **adding a duplicate-buster** - by extending [keyfield] to include some meaningless and otherwise unused unique value.

Answer (score 2):

How about *disambiguate*?  Webster’s dictionary defines it to be:

> to establish a single semantic or grammatical interpretation for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a single word, but you could say that you are changing ***a multiset into a true set***.

From Wikipedia:

> A [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) is a gathering together into a whole of definite, distinct
>   objects... every element of a set must be unique; no two members may
>   be identical.
>
> In mathematics, the notion of [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (or bag) is a
>   generalization of the notion of set in which members are allowed to
>   appear more than once.

Where did you get the word *uniquate*?  I couldn't find it anywhere.

If it's indeed an invented term, and you were writing a paper, you could define *uniquate* as *an operation that changes a bag, or multiset, into a true set*, and then use that term in subsequent places in the paper where you want to describe that operation.  You could even go further, and specify that the number of elements in the original multiset must remain constant:

> We define *uniquate* as an operation that changes a bag, or
>   multiset, into a true set, by replacing (not removing) any duplicate
>   elements.

Then, later in the paper:

> The next step of the process is to uniquate Bag B into Set B.

But I wouldn't use the word outright, without defining it first.  (Even if it is a real word, it appears rare enough that a formal definition within the document would be warranted).

Comment: Yes, it is invented to name a method in my code. Thanks for your good approach.

Comment: If it's a method name, then, following the suggestion of @Jay below, you might go with `MakeElementsUnique( )`.  (I assumed you were putting this into a document, not a program.)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to say this once or twice in whatever document you're preparing, I wouldn't use an obscure word or worse, invent a new word. Just use a short phrase to describe what you mean, like, "make all the values unique" or "replace all non-unique values with unique ones".

If it's something you need to say a million times to even a short phrase gets cumbersome, then: I don't know of any existing word. Mitch's suggestion of "uniquify" is not a bad neologism. Personally, though, I'd just say "make unique" and explain exactly what you mean on first use.