# Verb meaning "to make a list of elements unique"

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a verb that would mean `to make a list of elements unique`.

For example, let's say I have a list of elements and some of them can exist more then once in the list (duplicates).

What verb can I use for the action of removing such duplicates and make my list composed of unique elements only?

Comment: Possible answer: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48093/word-that-means-reduce-to-unique-parts

Comment: What if I don't want to remove duplicates, but for example rename them with a unique name, what would be the right verb to describe this action?

Comment: You could “setify” your list, i.e. assign your list variable to a set variable, and have the language’s built in functions remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **deduplication** (commonly used when storing large amounts of data on servers):

> Eliminate duplicate or redundant information from (something, especially computer data)

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deduplicate)

However, I think that “to make multiple elements unique” is something completely different!

Comment: I changed the title to clarify. I checked the definition, it's what I was looking for

Comment: There is also the informal term "uniquify" which is used in computing for small lists (eg. using the **-u** option to **sort**). This doesn't appear in major dictionaries but: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uniquify

Answer (score 0):

In a comment under your question you ask this:

> What if I don't want to remove duplicates, but for example rename them with a unique name, what would be the right verb to describe this action?

If this is what you *really* want to describe, then you're looking for an adverb, not a verb:

> I want to ***uniquely*** *name* the list elements.

That has nothing to with *removing* duplicate items (which is what *deduplication* means—and is a good answer if that's what you were looking for), but changing the names of duplicate items so that they are *no longer* duplicates—and *keeping* those renamed items.